# JQuery focus no campo

Tags: jquery

Existe algum método no jQuery que eu consiga focar no `input` com erro? Estou tentando fazer validação sem usar as libs de validação do *JQuery*. Meu problema é o seguinte: o usuário está no fim da tela e meu campo de validação está no meio. Queria redirecionar o usuário para o campo que está apresentando mensagem de validação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código do jQuery :**

```
   $(document).ready(function()
    { 
        $('#region_btnSave').click(function ()
        {  
            var txtHValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").val();
            var txtMValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").val();

            if (txtMValue == '' && txtHValue == '') {
                $("#errortxtM").text("Obrigatório").focus();
                $("#errortxtH").text("Obrigatório");
                $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").keydown(function () {
                    $("#errortxtM").text("").focus()
                });
                $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").keydown(function () {
                    $("#errortxtH").text("")
                }); 
                return false;
            } else if (txtMValue == '') {
                $("#errortxtM").text("Obrigatório");
                $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").keydown(function () {
                    $("#errortxtM").text("")
                });
                return false;

            } else if (txtHValue == '') {
                $("#errortxtH").text("Obrigatório");
                $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").keydown(function () {
                    $("#errortxtH").text("")
                });
                return false;
            }
            else {
                //not all text fields are valid
                $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").after('', null);
                $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").after('', null);
            }

    });
    });
```

**E o HTML:**

```
      <span class="error" id="errortxtM" style="color:#FF0000; font-size:10px"></span>
```

Ele ta fazendo a validação certinho porem se o usuário tiver no fim da tela ,ele não vai conseguir ver a mensagem de "Obrigatório".

Comment: Não deveria ser **`$("#errortxtM").focus();`** ao invés de `$("#errortxtM").text("Obrigatório").focus();`???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719269/assign-scroll-animation-to-focus-in-jquery

Neste post tem a solução para seu problema ele vai fazer um Scroll até o input com o erro.

Comment: `errortxtM` parece ser o `id` do texto abaixo do `input`, qual é o `id` do `input`? Porque é nele que você tem que dar o `focus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está aplicando `.focus()` num elemento que não aceita o método (`span`).

Ao focar no `input`, a tela automaticamente irá se deslocar para ele.

Como seu código tem muita redundância, tomei a liberdade e dei uma otimizada.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
    { 

       $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM, #region_tabVersao_N_txtH").keydown(function () {
           $(".error").text("");
       });

        $('#region_btnSave').click(function ()
        {  
            var txtHValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH");
            var txtMValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM");

            if (!txtMValue.val() && !txtHValue.val()) {
                txtHValue.focus();
                $("#errortxtH").text("Obrigatório");
            } else if (!txtMValue.val()) {
               txtMValue.focus();
                $("#errortxtM").text("Obrigatório");
            } else if (!txtHValue.val()) {
               txtHValue.focus();
                $("#errortxtH").text("Obrigatório");
            }
            else {
                //not all text fields are valid
                $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").after('', null);
                $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").after('', null);
                alert("ok");
            }
    });
 });
```

```css
div{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <input type="text" id="region_tabVersao_N_txtH" />
   <span class="error" id="errortxtH" style="color:#FF0000; font-size:10px"></span>
</div>
<div>
   <input type="text" id="region_tabVersao_N_txtM" />
   <span class="error" id="errortxtM" style="color:#FF0000; font-size:10px"></span>
</div>
<br />
Role para baixo e clique no botão
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<input value="Validar" type="button" id="region_btnSave" />
```

Comment: Deu certo,tem como no $("#errortxtH").text("Obrigatório"); colocar uma imagem junto?

Comment: @RobsonOliveira tem sim. Aí em vez de usar `text`, use `html`: `$("#errortxtH").html("<img src='url_da_imagem' />Obrigatório"); `

Comment: Oi @RobsonOliveira, vi que vc marcou a minha resposta e depois desmarcou. Achou a outra resposta melhor ou foi por engano?

Comment: Sorry ,acho que apertei mais de uma vez

Answer (score 2):

Você deve aplicar o `.focus` no `input`. Não vai funcionar caso você adicione em outro elemento como `span`, `div` etc.

Dessa forma:

```
$("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").focus().keydown(function() {
    $("#errortxtM").text("")
});
```

Ou ainda com JS Puro

```
document.querySelector("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").focus().keydown(function() {
    $("#errortxtM").text("")
});
```

**Exemplo com jQuery:**

```js
$('#region_btnSave').click(function() {
  var txtHValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").val();
  var txtMValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").val();

  if (txtMValue == '' && txtHValue == '') {
    $("#errortxtM").text("Obrigatório");
    $("#errortxtH").text("Obrigatório");
    $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").focus().keydown(function() {
      $("#errortxtH").text("")
    });

    $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").focus().keydown(function() {
      $("#errortxtM").text("")
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
}

span {
  color: Red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}

.big {
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="region_tabVersao_N_txtH">Input 1</label>
  <input id="region_tabVersao_N_txtH" />
  <span id="errortxtM"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="region_tabVersao_N_txtM">Input 2</label>
  <input id="region_tabVersao_N_txtM" />
  <span id="errortxtH"></span>
</div>

<div class="big">Desça a página</div>

<div>
  <button type="butotn" id="region_btnSave">Save</button>
</div>
```

**Js Puro**

```js
document.querySelector('#region_btnSave').addEventListener("click", () => {  
  var txtHValue = document.querySelector("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").value;
  var txtMValue = document.querySelector("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").value;

  if (txtMValue == '' && txtHValue == '') {
    document.querySelector("#errortxtM").innerText = "Obrigatório";
    document.querySelector("#errortxtH").innerText = "Obrigatório";
    
    document.querySelector("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").focus();
    
    document.querySelector("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").addEventListener("keydown", () => {
      document.querySelector("#errortxtM").innerText = "";
    });
    
     document.querySelector("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").addEventListener("keydown", () => {
      document.querySelector("#errortxtH").innerText = "";
    });
    
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
}

span {
  color:Red;
  display:block;
  width:100%
}

.big {
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="region_tabVersao_N_txtH">Input 1</label>
  <input id="region_tabVersao_N_txtH" />
  <span id="errortxtM"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="region_tabVersao_N_txtM">Input 2</label>
  <input id="region_tabVersao_N_txtM" />
  <span id="errortxtH"></span>
</div>

<div class="big">Desça a página</div>

<div>
  <button type="butotn" id="region_btnSave">Save</button>
</div>
```

> Não precisa adicionar `scrollTop`, exceto se você quiser uma animação. Exemplo abaixo.

```js
$('#region_btnSave').click(function() {
  var txtHValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").val();
  var txtMValue = $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").val();

  if (txtMValue == '' && txtHValue == '') {
    $("#errortxtM").text("Obrigatório");
    $("#errortxtH").text("Obrigatório");
    
    $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtM").keydown(function() {
      $("#errortxtH").text("")
    });

    $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").keydown(function() {
      $("#errortxtM").text("")
    });
    
    $("html,body").stop().animate({
      scrollTop:0
    }, 1000, function() {
      $("#region_tabVersao_N_txtH").focus()
    });
    
    return false;
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
}

span {
  color: Red;
  display: block;
  width: 100%
}

.big {
  height: 500px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="region_tabVersao_N_txtH">Input 1</label>
  <input id="region_tabVersao_N_txtH" />
  <span id="errortxtM"></span>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="region_tabVersao_N_txtM">Input 2</label>
  <input id="region_tabVersao_N_txtM" />
  <span id="errortxtH"></span>
</div>

<div class="big">Desça a página</div>

<div>
  <button type="butotn" id="region_btnSave">Save</button>
</div>
```